# Python MongoDB save dictionary of sets

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, set, pymongo

I have a dictionary of sets that I want to save persistently in the mongodb database. However, I receive the error "Cannot encode object: {1, 2}, of type: <class 'set'>" in the process of saving. I saw a post where one user's suggestion was to save each set as a dict but that didn't seem like a good solution to me. Is there any other way, other than transforming each set into a list, of saving the dictionary with sets? The dictionary looks something like the following code but more complex and with thousands of entries with a string key and set() values:

```
{'One': {1, 2}, 'Two': {3, 4}, 'Three': {5, 6}}
```

Comment: As which MongoDB type to you plan to store the sets?

Comment: I don't know the different possible types but that is actually not that important. As long as I can load the data and get a dictionary of sets again it does not matter which type.

Comment: Of cause it's important. MongoDB makes the rules about what can be saved within it. And sets are not part of these rules.

Comment: The plan is to receive sets in the end again. So wether the sets are saved as type x or type y is not important, if I can transform it easily into sets again. So I am open for any type as long as I can easily reconstruct the saved dictionary of sets.

Comment: JSON and BSON doesn't support sets, so the only way to save them is as arrays. If your driver complained means that it doesn't auto convert the sets to arrays while encoding to BSON. Solutions are change the driver code (the encode to BSON part) or convert them before inserting them to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB used to have SONManipulators to transform documents going in and coming out of the DB but they were deprecated in 4.0 .. so you have to preprocess your `set`s into objects for saving and restore them on load.

Example:

```
test = {'One': {1, 2}, 'Two': {3, 4}, 'Three': {5, 6}}

def unsetify(doc):
    for k, v in doc.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            doc[k] = unsetify(v)
        elif isinstance(v, set):
            doc[k] = { '_type': 'set', '_val': list(v) }
    return doc


def resetify(doc):
    for k, v in doc.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            if v.get('_type', '') == 'set':
                doc[k] = set(v['_val'])
            else:
                doc[k] = resetify(v)
    return doc

doc = unsetify(test)
print(doc)
print(resetify(doc))
```

Output:

```
{'One': {'_type': 'set', '_val': [1, 2]}, 'Two': {'_type': 'set', '_val': [3, 4]}, 'Three': {'_type': 'set', '_val': [5, 6]}}
{'One': {1, 2}, 'Two': {3, 4}, 'Three': {5, 6}}
```

Yes it's recursive and yes it clobbers the input document in-place instead of making a copy etc. May not be ideal for the exact use case (can't say without more info) but demonstrates the principle.